# How can I use Terraform to create a VM on a server by executing a .js file on systemd from a .js on a client?

Tags: node.js, terraform, virtual-machine

Why isn't `terraform apply` executing?

From a .js file on the client I want to visit a link with an axios.post on the server and get it to create a VM with Terrafom on the server.

There are two machines and both are in the room with me. Client passing the VM specs and the server I hope will create a VM with terraform.

This is pertinent part of the .js on the client
It contacts the .js file on the server, which is always listening over a systemd service. It sends the specifics for the VM to be created.

```
axios.post('http://192.168.0.152:3000/vms', {
  name: 'My_first_VM',
  cores: '4',
  memory: '4096',
  disk_size: '80G',
}, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImpvaG4uZG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNjc5NjY3Mjc5LCJleHAiOjE2Nzk3MDMyNzl9.wP5-XtA-7VRMg1ga4u5fS45oHV85DATMuPsLmo7DTI0'
  }
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

This is the pertinent part of the .js on the server
It is supposed to execute `terraform init` and `terraform apply` and pass the specs of the VM and create it.

```
app.post('/vms', verifyToken, (req, res) => {                                                                                                                                                 
  const { name, cores, memory, disk_size } = req.body;
  const cmd = `cd /home/presto/vm_scripts && terraform init -upgrade && terraform apply -no-color -var vm_name=${name} -var vm_cores=${cores} -var vm_memory=${memory} -var vm_disk_size=${disk_size} -auto-approve -v -log-level=debug`;
  
  exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error creating VM');
      return;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    res.send('VM created successfully');                                                                                                                                                      
  });
  console.log(req.body); // This will log the data sent in the request body                                                                                                                 
});
```

The full contents of the .tf file

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    null = {
      source = "hashicorp/null"
      version = "3.2.1"
    }
    libvirt = {
      source = "dmacvicar/libvirt"
      version = "0.7.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "libvirt" {
  uri = "qemu:///system"
}

resource "null_resource" "my_vm" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sudo bash /home/presto/vm_scripts/setup_vm.sh ${var.vm_name} ${var.vm_cores} ${var.vm_memory} ${var.vm_disk_size}"
  }
}

variable "vm_name" {
  default = "my-vm"
}

variable "vm_cores" {
  default = "4"
}

variable "vm_memory" {
  default = "4096"
}

variable "vm_disk_size" {
  default = "80G"
}
```

The full contents of the .sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

#install required packages
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install qemu-kvm virtinst bridge-utils

# Create virtual machine with desired specifications
sudo virt-install \
  --name ${vm_name} \
  --vcpus=${vm_cores} \
  --memory=${vm_memory} \
  --disk size=${vm_disk_size} \                                                                                                                                                               --network model=virtio, bridge=br0 \                                                                                                                                                        --graphics none \                                                                                                                                                                           --location 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/' \
  --extra-args 'console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8'
```

Below is the log for the .js I am running under a systemd process. It seems to be running `terraform init` but it I don't what is happening with what should be the `terraform apply` execution. I get no terraform files created in the directory.

```
{ name: 'My_first_VM', cores: '4', memory: '4096', disk_size: '80G' }
Mar 24 15:06:12 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: Initializing the backend...
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: Initializing provider plugins...
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: - Finding dmacvicar/libvirt versions matching "0.7.1"...
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: - Finding hashicorp/null versions matching "3.2.1"...
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: - Installing dmacvicar/libvirt v0.7.1...
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: - Installed dmacvicar/libvirt v0.7.1 (self-signed, key ID 96B1FE1A8D4E1EAB)
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: - Installing hashicorp/null v3.2.1...
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: - Installed hashicorp/null v3.2.1 (signed by HashiCorp)
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/plugins/signing.html
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: Terraform has been successfully initialized!
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]:
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: should now work.
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: Terraform v1.4.2
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: on linux_amd64
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.2.1
Mar 24 15:06:35 presto vm-creator.js[18037]: + provider registry.terraform.io/dmacvicar/libvirt v0.7.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing things two ways at once. I will separate them, and speak to their effectiveness independently.

**The Bash Way:**

I see no use-case for Terraform in the bash portion of this solution. Using a local-exec provisioner in a null resource is effectively the same as running the command to be executed outside of the context of Terraform. Run the bash script you wrote directly instead.

If you're using Terraform for the sake of its variable system (which is what this appears to be), you can do the same thing in `sh`, but the way you have it written won't work. It would have to look more like this, using positional arguments to the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#install required packages
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install qemu-kvm virtinst bridge-utils

# Create virtual machine with desired specifications
sudo virt-install \
  --name=$1 \
  --vcpus=$2 \
  --memory=$3 \
  --disk size=$4 \
  --network model=virtio, bridge=br0 \
  --graphics none \
  --location 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/' \                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  --extra-args 'console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8'
```

This has the benefit of being very simple, but does not solve for destruction or modification of VMs. This seems like a huge drawback to me, so you should probably use Terraform more idiomatically rather than trying to handle VMs via scripts.

**The Terraform Way:**

Get rid of your shell script and its associated null resource, and use the resources provided by the libvirt provider to do work. Given what you've written so far, I think this is what you're trying to go for (in addition to your existing libvirt provider and variables. Feel free to remove the null provider, as you're removing the null resource that requires it.

```
resource "libvirt_domain" "ubuntu" {
  name   = var.name
  memory = var.memory
  vcpu   = var.vcpu

  network_interface {
    model = "virtio"
    bridge = "br0"
  }

  console {
    type        = "pty"
    target_port = "0"
    target_type = "serial"
  }

  console {
    type        = "pty"
    target_type = "virtio"
    target_port = "1"
  }

  disk {
    url = "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/"
  }

  disk {
    volume_id = libvirt_volume.root.id
  }


}

resource "libvirt_volume" "root" {
  name = "ubuntu_root"
  size = var.disk_size
}
```

Refer to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/dmacvicar/libvirt/latest/docs/resources/volume and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/dmacvicar/libvirt/latest/docs/resources/domain for more documentation.

If you ever intend to use this module outside of the local machine its invoked on, you will need to use a non-local backend. Since your provider is set up to use a local host, and since you can use path-based routing to send API requests to specific hosts that execute their own local Terrform (or maybe it's all one machine), I don't yet see the need for non-local state in your solution.

Comment: "If you ever intend to use this module outside of the local machine its invoked on, you will need to use a non-local backend" I do intent to. Sorry, you lost me with this. You mean I can't make the server listen on 3000 and direct the client to 3000? I'm learning.

Comment: Sure, you can do that as long as the server is located on the qemu machine that its delivering resources to, or if there is only one server. When I refer to a non-local backend, I'm referring to that in the context of Terraform - which may use either a local state backend, or a remote (central) state backend via various methods (HTTPS, S3, PostgreSQL, etc).

If there is never anything but this one server doing work, remote state backends aren't strictly necessary.